# How do I populate a date textbox from a dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

I have a dropdown list with the names of the months listed in it.  These names are stored as int values but converted to string for display purpose.  I also have a RadDatePicker control that will allow the user to select a specific date to overwrite the default date.  The default date in the textbox needs to be set to the last day of the month selected (i.e. May 2010 would default to 05/31/2010).

Thanks

Comment: How is the year specified in the dropdown list? Is the int for the month name 0 based or 1 based?

Answer (score 0):

I would write some js that will stick in the tb.value the formatted date, otherwise you could do that in code behind, but in a postback 8-P. You can specify the formatting values reading the http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar_pickerformattingvalues.html

ps use a dictionary to match int value and txt representation if you neded it